# Manually increment a value in nested for loop in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor

I have nested for loop with `i` variable first and `j` variable second. I need to increment `i` value in nested for loop. here is my code:

```
 @for ( i= 0; i < Model.ItemMap.Count() ;i++ )
 {
    @{var PrevItem = Model.ItemMap.ToList()[i].ItemName;}                            
    @for (j= i; j < Model.ItemMap.Count(); j++)
     {
      if (PrevItem != Model.ItemMap.ToList()[j].ItemName)
       {
         break;                                                    
       }
       @i++;
     }                                        
}
```

in which "`@i++;`" throws error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax looks wrong.  try this

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ItemMap.Count(); i++)
{
    var prevItem = Model.ItemMap.ToList()[i].ItemName;
    for (var j = i; j < Model.ItemMap.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (prevItem != Model.ItemMap.ToList()[j].ItemName)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

not sure why you are incrementing i twice, but this doesn't throw any syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is `i++`, without the `@` - Razor knows you are already within a code segment.  Similarly, you shouldn't need to use code blocks for the following:

```
@for ( i= 0; i < Model.ItemMap.Count() ;i++ )
 {
    var PrevItem = Model.ItemMap.ToList()[i].ItemName;                            
    for (j= i; j < Model.ItemMap.Count(); j++)
```